# UvLechtecha VaDerech? With Kavanah?

Tags: travel, shema, kavana-concentration, petur-exemption, vaeschanan

How can one maintain Kavanah reciting Keriath Shema' [while walking along the way](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0506.htm#7)? Or is the requirement waived in this case?

Comment: +1, but the question is sorta lacking without evidence that the _pasuk_ is referring to "_Sh'ma_" itself. (_Bavli_, _Brachos_ 13, might supply such evidence.)

Comment: The Gemara says one should continue on his way. I believe RJB"S or one of his forebears stated that Shema' is a Davar SheBikdushah, which would normally normally require one to stand, but a special Gezerath HaKathuv that you say it in whatever place and position you're in when you start, meaning that the phrasing of the Pasuk is both intended to generalize the Halachah and to specifically require one to literally keep walking if one was walking when he started.

Comment: That was long, but the point is he's supposed to keep walking if he was already walking when the Zeman came. How can he maintain his focus? Or does he have to? I'll have to try to source this idea tomorrow.

Comment: I can't imagine he wouldn't need to have the minimal amount of concentration.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would you be lacking kavana cause you are walking?  You can't think and walk at the same time?

Comment: @avi, try it sometime.

Comment: @avi, maasim bechol yom you can text and drive at the same time.  Enough said.

Comment: @YDK I assume you meant to say "can't"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, they "can", but how good is their concentration on the road.

Comment: @YDK I see. I was confused because your analogies switch the movement and text components. Not problem just at first confusing (to me at least).

Comment: @YDK, I had the same reaction as Double AA, but I gotcha.

Comment: @SethJ  I often did, while learning and walking from my dorm to the Beit Midrash.  I actually still do it often when I walk to work and think upon my problems.

Comment: @YDK Driving and walking are two very different activities.  Driving taxes your eye brain coordination, walking does not.

Comment: @avi, I think that speaking to a friend while walking, and thinking to oneself while walking, are different from speaking in the abstract while walking. Furthermore, even if you do manage to keep your concentration on Shema', you are not paying close attention to your surroundings (hence the added danger while driving; walking doesn't carry that same danger, but it does carry the same distraction).

Comment: @avi, granted that walking is not as taxing on the brain, but anytime someone multitasks, his brain loses some focus on on one of the tasks to give to the other, whether to a lesser extent or greater.  So while someone who is walking will have more kavana than one who says shema while driving, he will have less than one who is immobile.

Comment: @YDK Not at all.  Your kavana will be just as much as when you are sitting down or any other position. Your ability to walk through an obstacle course might be hindered though. The problem with texting while driving isn't that your texts are incoherent, it's that your driving is unsafe!

Comment: @SethJ Infact, just this Friday night, I had to repeat the shema after Maariv and I said it while walking home.  Not only was my kavana great, but when I got to the line about "bderchecha" I had an added umph to my shema, just as one might touch their tefilin during those relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

This allowance is for someone to say the shema when he is already "on the path".  In such a circumstance, he will have more concentration if he says shema while continuing his journey than if we make him stop and delay his trip. For example, see [Shulchan Aruch OC 183:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14326&st=&pgnum=278).

Comment: +1, but a source would really be great.

Comment: Does the Shulchan Aruch's case have anything to do with the OP's pasuk?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the case is mentioned by benching, but is parallel.  183:9 requires one to sit for bentching so he may have kavana, 183:11 allows one to continue on one's way and not sit so he may have more kavana (assuming he will).

Comment: @YDK I was more interested in if that distinction is learned from the pasuk Uvlechtecha Vaderech.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that would imply that barring the pasuk there is a mitzva deoraisa inherent in shema that would require one to remain still and concentrate, which I don't believe is so.  The "requirement" to be still is a general law that applies to mitzvos of import, such as shema and benching.